# Service startup issue in YAJSW

Tags: java, yajsw

I am migrating script from jsw to yajsw.service installation works perfect.when i start service it shutdowns wrapper.I am using below command to start service.

> java -jar wrapper.jar -t cachenode-01/wrapper.conf

Log file:-

```
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:04|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:04|OS   : Windows 7/6.1/x86
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:04|JVM  : Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6.0_45/C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_45/32
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:04|started process with pid 38440
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:05|Shutting down Wrapper
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|OS   : Windows 7/6.1/x86
WARNING|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|JVM  : Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6.0_37/C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre/32
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|start delay: 0
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|Win service: before service init
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|+ ServiceMain callback
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|reporting status 0
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|reporting status 0
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:47|onstart
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|started process with pid 37524
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|calling onStop
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service stop - timeout: 30000
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service wrapper.control -> stopping application
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service stop - after shutdown
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service stop - before notify
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service terminated
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|reporting status 0
INFO|wrapper|17-03-14 13:17:48|Win service: terminated correctly
```

Can anyone please suggest why service is getting terminated and shuts down wrapper?